# Store the EdgeList as a unordered_set on Boost Graph Library

Tags: boost-graph, unordered-set

I'm reproducing an scientific experiment and I need to store the edge set of a graph as a unordered_set. I'm trying to use the BGL adjacency_graph and I think that the last parameter would be hash_setS intead of listS. But when I do that I get my program not working. I saw a similar question here where one person said to adapt the structure data to model de EdgeListGraph of the BGL, but I don't even have an idea how to do that.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Wow. Just post the code that's not working. Otherwise the answer is "Yes someone can help" and then <stunned silence/>

Comment: Hey sehe, thanks for reply. I don't know what I'v done, but it looks to work now, but I can't remember what exaclty I've changed. Nevertheless, I'll put the code here... Again, thaks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty, boost::hash_setS> Graph;

int main()
{

ifstream arquivo_in ("shrd150-3.dis");
ofstream arquivo_out ("matriz.txt");

int numero, j, i;
Graph g(15);
EdgeWeightProperty e;
enum { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O };
const char name[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";

boost::property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type
vertex_id = get(vertex_index, g);
boost::property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>::type
trans_delay = get(edge_weight, g);

j = 1;

for(i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    Graph::vertex_descriptor i = boost::add_vertex(g);


for(j = 1; !arquivo_in.eof(); ++j)
{
    for(i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        arquivo_in >> numero;
        e = numero;
        boost::add_edge(i, j, e, g);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if is storing as a hash_set, but I'll try a way to check collisions. Thanks again!

Comment: you mean, "check uniqueness constraints" right? Because a hash table should not leak collision info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to have "unordered_map" storage (you never mentioned). But since you said:

> I'm not sure if is storing as a hash_set, but I'll try a way to check collisions

I get the impression you just want to prevent duplicate edges. In that case, just use `setS` for the `OutEdgeList` container selector.

This container governs how the out-edges are stored for each vertex. If they are unique, then by definition the graph will not contain duplicate edges.

> **Note** that if the graph mode is `undirectedS` then Boost Graph Library will order the source/target vertices such that `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` edges are equivalent here/

### DEMO

*<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a8c245ca93eacf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty, boost::hash_setS> Graph;

int main()
{
    Graph g(15);

    assert( add_edge(0,1,g).second);
    assert( add_edge(1,2,g).second);
    assert( add_edge(0,2,g).second);
    assert( add_edge(0,3,g).second);
    assert(!add_edge(3,0,g).second);
}
```

Comment: Hi sehe. In my experiments I need to garantee that most of the operations under the edges would be done in constant time. I'll test it on very large instances of graphs. What I'm still unsure is if using hash_setS one the last parameter I would get the operations under the edge set in constant time, and how to check for collisions. Anyway, I'm so glad for your attention and will keep trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the edges separately for further processing, you can use a

```
boost::unordered_set<edge_desc>
```

by including

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
```

BGL documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/unordered/doc/html/unordered.html).